# Function write.csv returns an error

Tags: r, csv

The R function `write.csv` returns an error.

Here's the data.frame I want to write:

```
> VaRStats
               A Index    B Index      C Index
Daily VaR     -0.65006    -0.50391     -0.5557
Daily CVaR    -0.75679    -0.57491    -0.65174
5 Days VaR     -1.4204     -1.0077     -1.2269
```

Here's the class of `VaRStats`:

```
> class(VaRStats)
[1] "data.frame"
```

And here's the `dput()` output of `VaRStats`:

```
> dput(VaRStats)
structure(list(`JWFXA Index` = structure(list(`NA` = -0.650061101980277, 
    `NA` = -0.756791819719978, `JWFXA Index` = -1.42035638029947), .Names = c(NA, 
NA, "JWFXA Index")), `CCYT1 Index` = structure(list(`NA` = -0.503912574910245, 
    `NA` = -0.574907003405759, `CCYT1 Index` = -1.00773735259718), .Names = c(NA, 
NA, "CCYT1 Index")), `FX Multistrategy Index` = structure(list(
    `NA` = -0.555699685451229, `NA` = -0.651738541799373, `FX Multistrategy Index` = -1.22688572580144), .Names = c(NA, 
NA, "FX Multistrategy Index"))), .Names = c("JWFXA Index", "CCYT1 Index", 
"FX Multistrategy Index"), row.names = c("Daily VaR", "Daily CVaR", 
"5 Days VaR"), class = "data.frame")
```

The error generated though the `write.csv` function

```
> write.csv(VaRStats, "SummaryStats.csv")
Error in write.table(x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol, na, dec, as.integer(quote),  : 
  type 'list' not implemented in 'EncodeElement'
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Works fine for me... there must be a missing piece you're not providing.

Comment: Works fine here too. Maybe you could copy/paste a `dput` on your `VaRStats` object ?

Comment: I had a similar bizarre error recently - it was fixed by simply restarting R

Comment: @juba I posted the dput() output, the object was created via do.call("rbind",list(...))

Comment: lapply(VaRStats,class) suggests your columns are lists. That's probably the issue.

Comment: The structure you have is not really a data.frame. It has just been assigned the class "data.frame". Like ndoogan says, your columns are lists and not numbers. You can easily see this by performing sum(VaRStats) which will not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can simply do this :

```
      write.csv(as.matrix(dd), "SummaryStats.csv")
```

This works because all you columns are numeric.

```
read.csv("SummaryStats.csv")
         X JWFXA.Index CCYT1.Index FX.Multistrategy.Index
1  Daily VaR  -0.6500611  -0.5039126             -0.5556997
2 Daily CVaR  -0.7567918  -0.5749070             -0.6517385
3 5 Days VaR  -1.4203564  -1.0077374             -1.2268857
```

**EDIT**

This solution is the right one.

if you have a string in one of you list :

```
dd[1,1] <- 'a'

as.matrix(dd)
           JWFXA Index CCYT1 Index FX Multistrategy Index
Daily VaR  "a"         -0.5039126  -0.5556997            
Daily CVaR -0.7567918  -0.574907   -0.6517385            
5 Days VaR -1.420356   -1.007737   -1.226886
```

but using the `as.numeric` will fail or at least convert to NA

```
sapply(dd, as.numeric)
     JWFXA Index CCYT1 Index FX Multistrategy Index
[1,]          NA  -0.5039126             -0.5556997
[2,]  -0.7567918  -0.5749070             -0.6517385
[3,]  -1.4203564  -1.0077374             -1.2268857
Warning message:
```

Comment: nice (and important) follow up!

Answer (score 4):

For an unexplained reason, your data frame columns are lists, not vectors. You can transform your data frame back to a "normal" format with :

```
df <- sapply(VaRStats, as.numeric)
rownames(df) <- rownames(VarStats)
write.csv(df, "yourfile.csv")
```

Comment: (+1) but I think agstudy's solution is much more straightforward here.

Comment: @Arun I agree with you. Please upvote and accept agstudy's answer !

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are lists. They should be vectors. Try this.

```
VaRStats<-sapply(VaRStats,unlist)
write.csv(VaRStats,file="...")
```

Comment: initally mistakenly used lapply here, but changed it to sapply.

Comment: (+1) you could use `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))` (or cbind, if it gives the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a reproducible example, my guess is that you have a problem with `row.names` and `col.names`, also use `write.table` so that you can set all the arguments as you want

EDIT: I have the same problem look at `str` !!!

```
R) str(test)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ JWFXA Index           :List of 3
  ..$ NA         : num -0.65
  ..$ NA         : num -0.757
  ..$ JWFXA Index: num -1.42
 $ CCYT1 Index           :List of 3
  ..$ NA         : num -0.504
  ..$ NA         : num -0.575
  ..$ CCYT1 Index: num -1.01
 $ FX Multistrategy Index:List of 3
  ..$ NA                    : num -0.556
  ..$ NA                    : num -0.652
  ..$ FX Multistrategy Index: num -1.23
```

your data is not a commun `data.frame`

@juba has a good fix, use `lapply` to cast each list to a `numeric` vector

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the variable types of each of your columns. Write csv does not like columns of type list.

For example, in the starwars dataset, the columns films, vehicles and starships are of type list:

```
> data(starwars)
> class(starwars$vehicles)
[1] "list"
> class(starwars$starships)
[1] "list"
> class(starwars$films)
[1] "list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, VaRStats)

write.csv(df, "path\VaRStats.csv")
```

The first line transform from list to dataframe and then you can export to csv file